# LWC - Retrieving WAVE Dataset information

Tags: lightning, api, rest, einstein-analytics, component

I'm trying to make a callout to `/services/data/v45.0/wave/datasets` in a lightning web component. I can successfully make the callout for the running user in apex using `UserInfo.getSessionId()` but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent available for use in the javascript controller of a lwc. The data cannot be wired from the apex class, the callout errors out with invalid session id because `UserInfo.getSessionId()` isn't meant to work in methods decorated with `@AuraEnabled`.

I'd like to be able to distribute this component to different orgs freely. Is there a way to effectively retrieve this data client side in a way that is org / user agnostic? I've read about a workaround where user session id can be retrieved from a visualforce page, I'd rather not do this if possible.